# Is it possible to change the variable declared in a UMD module

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am including an older library that requires JQuery 2.2 but I would like to have everything else use the newest version of JQuery. The library in question mixes in using UMD(I think) so the code looks like this...

```
(function ($) {
  $.extend(true, window, {
    ...
  })
})(jQuery);
```

Is there a way that I can change the jQuery variable to be an older version than the one used by the rest of the application?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that when the library is loaded `window.jQuery` references the old jQuery version.

Once the library has been loaded with the old jQuery version you load the newer version and then load your application code.

```
<script src="old-jquery.js></script>
<script src="library.js"></script>
<script src="new-jquery.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

If you don't want to load the code in this order you can:

1. Load the new jQuery version
2. Load your app code
3. Load the old jQuery version
4. Load the plugin
5. Call `jQuery.noConflict()` - this will restore the new version of jQuery

Since jQuery 2.2 is relatively new you could also try loading the newest version of jQuery instead.

Comment: So this wouldn't reoverride the $ object or something? Like so if library gets called from app would the breaking changes made in 3.X manifest themselves?

Comment: The library would always use the old jQuery version. The jQuery object is passed into the IIFE on load and the library code keeps a reference to it. However, if the library is a jQuery plugin you can only use it with `oldJQ('#el').library()`, not `newJQ('#el').library()`. The new jQuery instance will not know that a plugin was added to the old jQuery instance.